# How to generate openapi json with NX?

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs, openapi, monorepo

I am having [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) projects in a Monorepo and [NX](https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro) is our build system.

I am looking for a way to compile and run a TS file at build time. The TS file has a logic to generate openapi.json file. TS file imports functions from main.js and other files in the project.

Code:

```
  
  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Cats example')
    .setDescription('The cats API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('cats')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  const outputPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'swagger.json');
  writeFileSync(outputPath, JSON.stringify(document), { encoding: 'utf8'});

  await app.close();
```

Issue: Since the NX generates a single file main.js. How I can compile and run my TS file?

P.S the same code works if I put it in bootstrap method of main.js but that is something I don't want.

Comment: Same. Basically after the equivilant of dotnets Swashbuckle `dotnet-tool swagger tofile` command